# How to Convert Recursion to Tail Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, tail-recursion

Is it always possible to convert a recursion into a tail recursive one?

I am having a hard time converting the following Python function into a tail-recursive one.

```
def BreakWords(glob):
  """Break a string of characters, glob, into a list of words.

  Args:
    glob: A string of characters to be broken into words if possible.

  Returns:
    List of words if glob can be broken down. List can be empty if glob is ''.
    None if no such break is possible.
  """
  # Base case.
  if len(glob) == 0:
    return []

  # Find a partition.
  for i in xrange(1, len(glob) + 1):
    left = glob[:i]
    if IsWord(left):
      right = glob[i:]
      remaining_words = BreakWords(right)
      if remaining_words is not None:
        return [left] + remaining_words

  return None
```

Comment: You're aware that Python doesn't optimize tail recursion (nor tail calls in general)? You'll also need to store some data elsewhere for some algorithms.

Comment: I'm hoping if I can convert it into tail-recursion, then it's easy to convert it into iterations.

Comment: In general, the way to convert a recursive function into a tail-recursive one is to pass along an accumulator. The only thing that makes that hard in this case is that your recursive call is inside an iterative loop. I think it will be much easier to just convert this to iteration directly. Would that be an acceptable answer here?

Comment: @abarnert, I suppose so. That would mean I have to implement backtracking manually. I was hoping there is some cleverer way.

Comment: @kirakun: Well, you could turn the iterative loop into a second level of recursion, then flatten the two functions together, then convert the resulting function to tail recursion, then convert that to iteration… I just don't think that'll be any easier to accomplish or to understand than adding a manual state-stack.

Answer (score 2):

I'n not sure if is always the case, but most of recursive functions can be implemented as tail recursives. Besides Tail Recursion is different from Tail Recursion optimization.

### Differences Tail Recursion and "Regular" ones

#### There are two elements that must be present in a recursive function:

1. The recursive call
2. A place to keep count of the return values.

#### A "regular" recursive function keeps (2) in the stack frame.

The return values in regular recursive function are composed of two types of values:

- Other return values
- Result of the owns function computation

Let's see a example:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1 return 1
    return n * factorial(n-1)
```

The frame f(5) "stores" the result of it's own computation (5) and the value of f(4), for example. If i call factorial(5), just before the stack calls begin to colapse, i have:

```
 [Stack_f(5): return 5 * [Stack_f(4): 4 * [Stack_f(3): 3 * ... [1[1]]
```

Notice that each stack stores, besides the values i mentioned, the whole scope of the function. So, the memory usage for a recursive function f is O(x), where x is the number of recursive calls i have to made. So, if i needb 1kb of RAM to calculate factorial(1) or factorial(2), i need ~100k to calculate factorial(100), and so on.

#### A Tail Recursive function put (2) in it's arguments.

In a Tail Recursion, i pass the result of the partial calculations in each recursive frame to the next one using parameters. Let's see our factorial example, Tail Recursive:

```
def factorial(n):
    def tail_helper(n, acc):
        if n == 1 or n == 2: return acc
        return tail_helper(n-1, acc + n)
return tail_helper(n,0)
```

Let's look at it's frames in factorial(4):

```
[Stack f(4, 5): Stack f(3, 20): [Stack f(2,60): [Stack f(1, 120): 120]]]]
```

See the differences? **In "regular" recursive calls the return functions recursively compose the final value. In Tail Recursion they only reference the base case (last one evaluated)**. We call **accumulator** the argument that keeps track of the older values.

### Recursion Templates

The regular recursive function go as follows:

```
def regular(n)
    base_case
    computation
    return (result of computation) combined with (regular(n towards base case))
```

To transform it in a Tail recursion we:

- Introduce a helper function that carries the accumulator
- run the helper function inside the main function, with the accumulator set to the base case.

Look:

```
def tail(n):
    def helper(n, accumulator):
        if n == base case:
            return accumulator
        computation
        accumulator = computation combined with accumulator
        return helper(n towards base case, accumulator)
    helper(n, base case)
```

### Your example:

I did something like this:

```
def BreakWords(glob):
    def helper(word, glob, acc_1, acc_2):
        if len(word) == 0 and len(glob) == 0:
            if not acc_1:
                return None
            return acc
        if len(word) == 0:
            word = glob.pop[0]
            acc_2 = 0

        if IsWord(word.substring[:acc_2]):
            acc_1.append(word[:acc_2])
            return helper(word[acc_2 + 1:], glob, acc_1, acc_2 + 1)

        return helper(word[acc_2 + 1:], glob, acc_1, acc_2 + 1)

    return helper("", glob, [], 0)
```

In order to eliminate the for statement you made, i did my recursive helper function with 2 accumulators. One to store the results, and one to store the position i'm currently trying.

### Tail Call optimization

Since no state is being stored on the Non-Border-Cases of the Tail Call stacks, they aren't so important. Some languages/interpreters then substitute the old stack with the new one. So, with no stack frames constraining the number of calls, **the Tail Calls behave just like a for-loop**.

But unfortunately for you Python isn't one of these cases. You'll get a RunTimeError when the stack gets bigger than 1000. [Mr. Guido](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html)
 thinks that the clarity lost to debugging purposes due to Tail Call Optimization (caused by the frames thrown awy) is more important than the feature. That's a shame. Python has so many cool functional stuff, and tail recursion would be great on top of it :/